# wxPython: How to make a TextCtrl fill a Panel

Tags: python, wxpython

How do I set the size of a multi-line TextCtrl to always fill its parent panel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `boxSizer`.

When you add your `textCtrl` to the sizer set the proportion to `1` and pass the `wx.EXPAND` flag, that way your `textCtrl` should fill the panel even when the panel is resized

```
bsizer = wx.BoxSizer()
bsizer.Add(yourTxtCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

Put the following at the end of your panels initialization to set the layout

```
self.SetSizerAndFit(bsizer)
```